# How to get full Address from Google PlaceAutoComplete fragment?

Tags: android, location, google-places

I want to get the full address when a location is selected. Here is an example of my scenario.

[image]

When I select Uttara, I get only Uttara if I apply place.getName(). If I apply place.getAddress(), I only get Uttara, Bangladesh. How I can I get Uttara, Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh ? Please help guys.....

Here is my code snippet:

```
 PlaceAutocompleteFragment places= (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment_pick);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) places.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment_pick);
        ll.setPadding(-7,-7,-7,-7);
        etPickPlace = (EditText)places.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input);
        etPickPlace.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        etPickPlace.setTextSize(18.0f);
        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setCountry("BD")
                .build();

        places.setFilter(typeFilter);
        places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                //Here I want to get the full pick up address
                pickAddress = place.getAddress().toString();
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),place.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `place.getAddess()` only by this. If you want the full address and more correct you need to implement GeoCode APIs.

Following class is the key element for reverse geocoding to get the address for the passed latitude and longitude coordinates. We access the enter code here's Geocoder Google API for reverse geocoding and get every line of address like street, city, pin/zip code and etc.

LocationAddress.java

```
public class LocationAddress {

private static final String TAG = "LocationAddress";
public static void getAddressFromLocation(final double latitude, final double longitude,
                                          final Context context, final Handler handler) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            String result = null;
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                    result = sb.toString();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
            } finally {
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.setTarget(handler);
                if (result != null) {
                    message.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    result = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude +
                            "\n\nAddress:\n" + result;
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                } else {
                    message.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    result = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude +
                            "\n Unable to get address for this lat-long.";
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                }
                message.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
}
```

Hope this will help to fulfill your requirements.

For your reference: [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place)

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I want address from Places Autocomplete Fragment. Here it is - https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Comment: Kindly check "Get place predictions programmatically" on the same page for your expected result. Hope you will find solution.

Comment: I've seen those procedures before but now I am seeing this in a whole new vision ! Thanks man, I will definitely try out different combinations till I get desired result.